# PHP/APACHE and MySQL SERVER Setup

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, capacity-planning

I'm about to setup a server hosting MySQL, Apache/PHP, File Uploads, and probably CCTV Storage.

> **Planned Personal Server Specifications:**
>
> - ASUS H97M-E
> - INTEL i7-4790
> - 2 x 4GB 1600MHz RAM
> - KINGSTON V300 120GB SSD
> - 2 x 3TB SEAGATE 7200RPM HDD

This will be my first time setting up a server, and I haven't decided a good Operating System for this. I'll also be setting up RAID 1 for backup.

Well, as projected, the server will host a simple EHR System, DTR System, Inventory System, Accounting System, Billing System and Cashiering System in one Web Program, with only 13 Users.

I am kinda worried about the traffic since the System will serve at least 100 clients per hour.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Are the specs listed too overkill for its task?
2. Is RAID 1 good for the setup? If no, what are your suggested RAID setups and how can we expand its storage later?
3. What's the best Operating System for this?

Your suggestions and answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to remove "personal" from the question so people don't accidentally close this since it sounds like it's actually for business purposes.

Comment: 1. Dunno - you need to test it with your expected load. 2. No one can decide this except yourself. 3. Whatever you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score -3):

The answer to the first question really depends on how CPU intensive the software is going to be, but should be able to cope with 100 clients per hour

RAID is slowly going obsolete, however unless you are deploying larger scale NAS/SAN with this it will work fine. As for which type of RAID, with 2 disks you are pretty much only able to do 0 and 1, so do 1.

Operating system depends, again, on the software you will be running. If you want enterprise-class go with CentOS, however it has quite old versions of some packages so keep that in mind. Otherwise for general purposes I suggest Debian.

Comment: The Program is pretty simple, I believe. It's more like an eCommerce kind of program.

Comment: "RAID is slowly going obsolete" Wat. That is most certainly not the case.

Comment: @EEAA A malfunctioning drive in a RAID array that uses parity will rip your data integrity apart. Memory-trusting filesystems like ZFS and BTRFS with error-correcting RAM are superior.

Comment: @Seth You're throwing the baby out with the bathwater. RAID is not going anywhere. Yes, ZFS/BTRFS are great, but they're not a panacea. Additionally, they're completely un-usable with a large majority of the storage controllers that are being sold now. RAID is not going anywhere, not for a long time.